# SpringData query on two database

Tags: spring-data

I need query two data bases with springdata. This is my configuration:

Cosmos-dao.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
 xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd  
                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  
                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd  
                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop  
                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <!--
    ////////////// DATA SOURCES /////////// 
     -->
    <bean id="orbeDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence" />
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@bddesarrollo.ccd.junta-andalucia.es:1526:DESA10G" />
      <property name="username" value="orbe" />
      <property name="password" value="etorbi" />
    </bean> 
    <bean id="cosmosDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence" />
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@bddesarrollo.ccd.junta-andalucia.es:1526:DESA10G" />
      <property name="username" value="cosmos" />
      <property name="password" value="cosmos" />
    </bean>

    <!--
    //////////// ENTITY MANAGER FACTORY /////////// 
     -->
    <bean id="orbeEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="orbeDataSource" />
      <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
      </property>
      <property name="packagesToScan" value="es.juntadeandalucia.ccul.cosmos.modelodatos.repositorios.orbe" />
      <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    </bean> 
    <bean id="cosmosEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="cosmosDataSource" />
      <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
      </property>
      <property name="packagesToScan" value="es.juntadeandalucia.ccul.cosmos.modelodatos.repositorios.comos" />
      <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    </bean> 

        <!--
    /////////// TRANSACTION MANAGER PER DATASOURCE //////////// 
     -->
    <bean id="orbeTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="orbeEntityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="cosmosTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="orbeEntityManagerFactory" />
    </bean> 
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="orbeTransactionManager" />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="cosmosTransactionManager" />


    <jpa:repositories base-package="es.juntadeandalucia.ccul.cosmos.modelodatos.repositorios.orbe" 
                      transaction-manager-ref="orbeTransactionManager" 
                      entity-manager-factory-ref="orbeEntityManagerFactory" >
    </jpa:repositories>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="es.juntadeandalucia.ccul.cosmos.modelodatos.repositorios.cosmos" 
                      transaction-manager-ref="cosmosTransactionManager"
                      entity-manager-factory-ref="cosmosEntityManagerFactory" >
    </jpa:repositories>

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
      <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I have used two dataSource, entitimanager and transactionManager. I follow the post:

http://blog.springsource.org/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/  (Oliver Gierke reply) and

[Spring Data + JPA with multiple datasources but only one set of Repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12612288/spring-data-jpa-with-multiple-datasources-but-only-one-set-of-repositories)

Persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" 
             xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
                                 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="cosmosPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
                <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy" />
                <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
                <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
                <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
                <!-- <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" /> -->
        </properties>
</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="orbePU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
                <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy" />
                <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
                <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
                <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
                <!-- <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" /> -->
        </properties>
</persistence-unit>

<!--
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/cosmosDS</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>

-->
</persistence>
```

My repositories:

```
   package es.juntadeandalucia.ccul.cosmos.modelodatos.repositorios.orbe;

    import java.util.List;

    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

    import es.juntadeandalucia.ccul.cosmos.modelodatos.entidades.orbe.Categoria;
    import es.juntadeandalucia.ccul.cosmos.modelodatos.entidades.orbe.Categorizacion;

    /**
     * <b>Proyecto:</b> COSMOS<br>
     * <b>Package:</b> es.juntadeandalucia.ccul.cosmos.modelodatos.repositorios<br>
     * <b>Fecha</b>: 28-05-2012<br>
     * Interfaz del repositorio de la entidad Categoria
     */
    public interface RepositorioCategoria extends JpaRepository<Categoria, Long>, RepositorioCategoriaCustom{ 
        public List<Categoria> findByCtzXCategorizacion(Categorizacion categorizacion);
    }

package es.juntadeandalucia.ccul.cosmos.modelodatos.repositorios.orbe;

/**
 * <b>Proyecto:</b> COSMOS<br>
 * <b>Package:</b> es.juntadeandalucia.ccul.cosmos.modelodatos.repositorios<br>
 * <b>Fecha</b>: 28-05-2012<br>
 * Interfaz del repositorio de la entidad Categoria
 */
public interface RepositorioCategoriaCustom {
}
```

Implementation:

```
package es.juntadeandalucia.ccul.cosmos.modelodatos.repositorios.orbe.impl;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.QueryDslRepositorySupport;

import es.juntadeandalucia.ccul.cosmos.modelodatos.repositorios.orbe.RepositorioCategoriaCustom;

/**
 * <b>Proyecto:</b> COSMOS<br>
 * <b>Package:</b> es.juntadeandalucia.ccul.cosmos.modelodatos.repositorios.impl<br>
 * <b>Fecha</b>: 28-05-2012<br>
 * Clase que implementa la interfaz del repositorio de la entidad Categoria
 */

public class RepositorioCategoriaImpl extends QueryDslRepositorySupport implements RepositorioCategoriaCustom {

    protected Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
}
```

Why i get this error?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'categoriasBOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private es.juntadeandalucia.ccul.cosmos.modelodatos.repositorios.orbe.RepositorioCategoria es.juntadeandalucia.ccul.cosmos.negocio.bo.impl.CategoriasBOImpl.repositorioCategoria; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositorioCategoria': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'repositorioCategoriaImpl' while setting bean property 'customImplementation'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositorioCategoriaImpl': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3795)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private es.juntadeandalucia.ccul.cosmos.modelodatos.repositorios.orbe.RepositorioCategoria es.juntadeandalucia.ccul.cosmos.negocio.bo.impl.CategoriasBOImpl.repositorioCategoria; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositorioCategoria': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'repositorioCategoriaImpl' while setting bean property 'customImplementation'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositorioCategoriaImpl': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositorioCategoria': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'repositorioCategoriaImpl' while setting bean property 'customImplementation'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositorioCategoriaImpl': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.Abs26-nov-2012 12:29:22 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
GRAVE: Error listenerStart
26-nov-2012 12:29:22 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
GRAVE: Falló en arranque del Contexto [/cosmos] debido a errores previos
tractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:848)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:790)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositorioCategoriaImpl': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 2
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 2
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:537)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:496)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:630)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:159)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:339)
    ... 51 more
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.